# Proxy configuration change

Tags: proxy

There used to be an option in proxy configuration that was:

```
Use this proxy server for all protocols
```

However, in 12.04, I can't find it. Is there anyway to reproduce its behavior in a handy way? I can't seem to find it.

I tried to install `gnome-network-properties` to get the old applet back but sadly it's part of `gnome-control-center` and I have that installed already.

Any hint on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to reproduce its behavior in a handy way?

Well, the handiest way is good old copy-and-paste! (see screenshot below)  Usually an HTTP/HTTPS proxy will not also do FTP/SOCKS, while a SOCKS proxy will handle everything. But if the "Apply to all protocols" setting worked for you before, no reason why it shouldn't now.

[image: Screenshot of Network Proxy Configuration]

Comment: Oh ok I thought that was gonna handle only 4 protocols when many more could have been handled. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: I wonder where this information goes to. Which config file?