# How do I find which proxy and port I am connected to?

Tags: proxy, vpn

I believe that I am connected to a proxy over a vpn connection.   Where can I find which proxy I am connected to and ports

Answer (score 0):

You may use `curl` to investigate it:

```
 curl -v https://askubuntu.com/questions/267104 >/dev/null
```

In the output you will see:

```
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.example.org
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy.example.org:3128
Via: 1.0 example.computer42.org (squid)
```

Also you may investigate the configuration of your web browser, if the proxy configuration is part wise automated, but the shell environment stuff used by `curl` is forgotten.

To get an idea how this automatic configuration may be done, have a look here:
[Set web proxy using pac-file-url](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263567/set-web-proxy-using-pac-file-url-in-lubuntu/263596#263596)

Comment: Ok, thanks this is a sub question to another about failed apt-get proxy Auth failures.

Comment: It's a clear answer which I will try tonight and if it doesn't work I'll repost.

Comment: @Ray If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.