# Google Chrome proxy settings?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

When I try to set Google Chrome's proxy settings (on chrome://linux-proxy-config/), I get the following message:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the
>   system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
>   supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man
>   google-chrome-stable for more information on flags and environment
>   variables.

I need to set proxy settings to use Chrome, but I don't want to be setting them in the command line every time I use Chrome. Is there a way to set these settings permanently?

Also, is there an option in Chrome so that it doesn't use proxy for specific domains (analogous to the `No proxy for` setting in Firefox)?

Comment: @KasiyA I don't want to use Chrome without proxy. I want to use proxy for most domains, except for a few, which are local to my network.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Open a Terminal and type `sudo -H nautilus`

Type your password then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and type `/usr/share/applications/` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now find `google-chrome` and right-click on chrome icon and select "Properties".

Next, Add the following option at the end of command text box, there.

`--proxy-server="IP proxy Server:port"` (ex: `--proxy-server="127.0.0.1:8080"`)

it's look like this (*it's the same for Chrome*):

[image]
close the window and if the chrome browser is still running, then close the browser and restart again. Finally you can use chrome browser with proxy.

[--proxy-bypass-list](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#proxy-bypass-list):

If you want to tell google-chrome to NOT use a proxy with specific domains use `--proxy-bypass-list` command. This command specifies a list of hosts for whom we bypass proxy settings and use direct connections. Ignored if `--proxy-auto-detect` or `--no-proxy-server` are also specified. This is a comma-separated list of bypass rules.

Here is List of [Chromium Command Line](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-proxy-server) that used in google-chrome too.

Comment: How do I tell google chrome to NOT use a proxy with specific domains? Something like the option `No proxy for` in Firefox?

Comment: How would one specify the username/password when using --proxy-server?

Comment: @user2813274 you should use this syntax `user:password@proxy:port` (for an example: `--proxy-server="USERhere:PASShere@127.0.0.1:8080"`)

Comment: What is the syntax for --proxy-bypass-list? Should I just list the bypassed hosts after it? Should I use ="list"? List entries are separated by what? Semicolons? Commas? Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: @αғsнιη can you? I thought this was not supported? (I get this error net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES ) at least on Chrome,...

Comment: Chromium has been silently ignoring proxy arguments for the past couple of years, at least on Linux. I know this is how you're "supposed to do it", but it simply doesn't work and there is nothing you can do except use a different browser.

Comment: gksu has been removed from ubuntu since v 18

Answer (score 20):

Google Chrome and Chromium obey the environment proxy variables (`http_proxy`, `no_proxy`, etc.) and the proxies set via [`gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gsettings.1.html). `gsettings` comes preinstalled on [XL]ubuntu, so this is one way which doesn't need `sudo` privileges.

The keys `org.gnome.system.proxy.http[s].{host,port,authentication-user,authentication-user}` (and similar options for FTP and SOCKS proxies) and the proxy autoconfiguration key `org.gnome.system.proxy.autoconfig_url` can be used for this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host "proxy.server.fqdn"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port "3128"
```

A proxy exception list can be set using the `ignore-hosts` key:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '::1', '*.some.domain', '10.0.0.0/8']"
```

A `no_proxy` environment variable would look like:

```
export no_proxy="localhost,.some.domain,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8"
export NO_PROXY="localhost,.some.domain,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8"
```

You can set this in `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment` (without the `export`).

Comment: I have a different experience. Chrome 61.0.3163.100 on Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't seem to use http_proxy and https_proxy vars. They are set for my user in ~/.profile, which is the same user Chrome is started with, but Chrome can't connect..

Comment: @Julius which DM?

Comment: Dear @muru, can I set a proxy username and password by using gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http ?

Comment: Setting the `gsettings` values, which map to Ubuntu's system proxy in its UI, is the only way I could get Chrome to use my corporate proxy. Using Ubuntu 18.04.4 + Chrome 80, the _proxy and _PROXY env vars do NOT seem to be used, which is what Firefox seems to do.

Comment: Only org.gnome.system.proxy.http has the authentication-* keys, org.gnome.system.proxy.https lacks them. How can I add them there, too?

Comment: @jhasse apparently there's no way currently: https://github.com/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.system.proxy.gschema.xml.in#L96 (in the past I ran my own squid server locally to perform authentication)

Answer (score 14):

Just execute below command in terminal

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

in Command value append below line

```
--proxy-server="192.168.1.251:8080"
```

Change it with your proxy. its example of non - authentication proxy. For a proxy with authentication one should use,

```
--proxy-server="username:password@proxy_address:port"
```

Comment: Very nice, and it also works with Chrome apps.

Comment: for `chromium`, the particular file is `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` and the particular setionc is `Exec` - you must put the proxy line into all `Exec` appearences across this file

Comment: sometime chrome is stuck with `waiting for proxy server`. so adding `--no-proxy-server` option saves the day. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every time chromium package gets updated, desktop file is overwritten, and the setting is lost.

Answer (score 7):

**For Unity**: In "system settings", go to "network" then "network proxy" : you can then set your proxy system wide.

For setting user and password , set it like this :
user:password@proxy:port

**For Lubuntu , Xubuntu etc...**: look this thread [How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio)

Comment: I am using Lubuntu. Where do I find "System Settings"?

Comment: Yep, answer was for Unity .May be you use command:  export http_proxy="user:password@proxy:port"     then command for chrome, in a 2 line script.

Comment: Google Chrome is currently not taking care of system-wide proxy settings.

Comment: This, IMHO, shoudl be the accepted answer. Google will use the system proxy.

Answer (score 5):

### Semi-automated way

I have found [@αғsнιη](https://askubuntu.com/users/283843/kasiya) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/513870/427933) to be most helpful.

However, every **update** of Google Chrome resulted in resetting the desktop entry and `proxy` settings. **It is quite frustrating editing it again, and again.**

---

Instead of manual work, you can change the entry with a short script.

Simply paste it to terminal:

```
sudo sed '/^Exec/s/$/ --proxy-server="10.0.2.2:3128"/' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop  -i
```

Obviously, you need to change the IP to your proxy server.

---

This appends all lines starting with `Exec` with your proxy setting, which is the manual way of setting the proxy.

**Enjoy!**

Comment: Since Chrome/mium tends to stay semi-open in the taskbar, there's really no need to append proxy parameters to every `Exec` instance. Just the main one (named `Chromium Web Browser`) is usually enough. The rest of `Exec` instances are used for actions like opening a new window, which usually happen once the browser is up and running.

Answer (score 3):

[How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio) points to the file `/etc/environment` where you can insert the following lines as root:

```
http_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
https_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

[The top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/151047/438156) (very elaborate) also contains a script to enable/disable on demand. (But if you need that, Firefox has an options page for choosing the proxy and you might want to consider using it).

Answer (score 3):

When the proxy settings are in the environment proxy variables, **Chrome** did not work by putting the full proxy settings on the launcher.

`--proxy-server="IP proxy Server:port" (ex: --proxy-server="127.0.0.1:8080")`

But it worked when I put it to detect the automatic configurations

`--proxy-auto-detect`

And it worked in **Vivaldi**.

Answer (score 2):

One option I use is [the Proxy SwitchyOmega extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif). It allows some IP addresses or domains to be exempted, as you ask for.

It has a nice GUI instead of needing to deal with command line arguments. It also supports Chrome Sync, so you can get up and running with your proxy settings on a new computer quickly.

You can also set it up so that using the proxy can be switched on or off with a single click.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

--> in Exec value append below line

```
--proxy-server="10.1.6.14:3128"
```

(enter your nw proxy instead of 10.1.6.14 and port instead of 3128)

example:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %--proxy-server="10.1.6.14:3128"
```