# My browsers can not connect to the internet while my Ubuntu is connected

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, connection, browser

I am using Ubuntu 1604, and I am connected to a WiFi network.
My computer is connected, I can download and install updates, I can use skype, telegram desktop and everything but my google chrome browser and firefox browser can not access the Internet!

What's wrong with my Ubuntu?

---

I try the only answer and now I have my firefox again!

But I can't set the chrome proxy to be "no proxy" or "direct".
I tried the solutions from [Google Chrome proxy settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513840/google-chrome-proxy-settings/513956#513956),
but still have the problem!

Could you please help me?!

Comment: Please do not put `SOLVED` in the title, just check the checkmark onto the answer which was most helpful for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by the following steps:

1) Open FireFox and enter `about:preferences` in the URL.

2) In the General tab scroll to the bottom.

3) Under the Network Proxy header click on `Settings...`

4) At the top, choose `Auto detect proxy settings for this network`

5) Click OK

type `www.askubuntu.com` in the URL bar and see if it works!

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

This occurred to me when I updated firefox. It occurred because by default firefox use IPv6 protocol. You need to disable that.

Try this:

1) In search tab, type `about:config`
2) Accept the safety prompt
3) Search for `network.dns.disableIPv6`
4) Make sure its value is set to `true`. You can change it by double tapping it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This did the trick for me on Lubuntu 18.10. Just wondering, how did you find this out?

Comment: As far as I recall, I got this after searching for hours on some github issue!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by modifying the resolver configuration file with the following steps:

1. Open the file /etc/resolv.conf
2. Change the line:

   ```
   nameserver x.x.x.x
   ```

   to:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** `8.8.8.8` is the IP address for Google's DNS service. If you would prefer a different DNS service, replace the IP above with the one you prefer.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

open firefox
write
about:preferences

go advanced-Network

revise proxy settings

more help can be see here.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can

you are welcome, plese tell me if work or if you have any question.

Comment: My firefox browser can browse pages now, but google chrome still have the problem! I tried the same method for it, but I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: For Chrome, try [the Proxy SwitchyOmega extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif). It'll let you set Chrome to use a direct connection (or whatever other proxy settings you want).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I am facing on Ubuntu 18.04. But for now I am giving proxy to google-chrome by terminal.

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="http://xxxx:port"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after I removed .mozilla directory under the home directory, problem solved.

pc: I lost all my bookmarks and search history, please take into consideration.