# Internet not working on Firfox and Chromium, but works on Tor

Tags: networking, firefox, network-manager, internet, chromium

I have problem with internet connection for Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu[ Ubuntu 16.04]. I tried few solution. One of them is [My browsers can not connect to the internet while my Ubuntu is connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928127/my-browsers-can-not-connect-to-the-internet-while-my-ubuntu-is-connected). But no one works.
May be  proxy/or firewall problem??

**Ping 8.8.8.8:**

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

**Ping google.com:**

```
ping https://www.google.com
ping: unknown host https://www.google.com
```

**nmcli d:**

```
    virbr0     bridge     connected      virbr0
    enp0s25    ethernet   unmanaged      ---
    lo         loopback   unmanaged      ---
```

Any help regrading this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you ping your gateway?  I suspect you can; can you ping a web-site externally using internet address (eg. `ping 8.8.8.8` or google) again I suspect you can.  Next can you ping using a human address (eg. `ping google.com`) - I suspect here you'll find you can't - ie. you have a DNS issue.  Tor uses a different DNS system (otherwise it wouldn't be private!) so your issue is likely DNS.

Comment: Please don't reply in comments, if you want to add information - edit your question and add it there, it's easier to read, allows editing & provides formatting options now available in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix DNS resolving which doesn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s)

Comment: Not at all, these websites works normally.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s not working

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: `ping https://www.google.com` ... you don't use URL notation in ping, just FQDN. It should be: `ping www.google.com`

Comment: What about output of `/sbin/route -n`, `host 8.8.8.8`, `nslookup ubuntu.com`, and `wget --spider ubuntu.com`?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver: Output of /sbin/route -n is binary.
host 8.8.8.8 & nslookup ubuntu.com silently hangs up.
wget --spider ubuntu.com prompts "Resolving ubuntu.com … failed: Name or service not known."

Comment: @abbasi_ahsan Please update your question with those results. Also try `systemd-resolve ubuntu.com` and `getent hosts ubuntu.com`. What do you mean by "Output of /sbin/route -n is binary"? It should say "Kernel IP routing table", followed by a table with columns that say e.g. "Destination" and "Gateway".

Comment: what do you have here `cat /etc/resolv.conf` ?