# No internet through Web Browser

Tags: networking, 18.04, firefox, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, but recently I am not able to use the internet without using VPN service provided by Opera, When I run google searches in Mozilla Firefox I am getting the error as ***An error occurred during a connection to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR***

while running search from opera without VPN I am getting the error as ***"ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"***

I am able to get ping from google.com without using VPN from the terminal.

Any thoughts on why this is occuring and possible fixes would be much appreciated.

EDIT : following the steps to disable ipv6 from the link below fixed firefox issue, still the software updater is complaining unable to connect the internet, also Opera not working without VPN.

firefox working fix link : https://askubuntu.com/a/1104680/1191244
Thanks

Comment: Can you successfully run commands that fetch files from the internet, e.g.`sudo apt update`?

Comment: Have you tried using `duckduckgo`? I use it in FF on 20.04 without issue. link [here](https://duckduckgo.com/)