# update from 20.04 to 22.04 : internet connection OK everywhere except browsers (firefox and chromium)

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, chromium

I updated my ubuntu to the new version 22.04.

I can download packages via apt install, I can use some software like slack who need internet connection

...but, my browsers can't navigate on internet :/ I don't understand why...
By example, when I open firefox, I get this page :

[image]

I tried some proposed solutions :

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1104680/621125
- https://askubuntu.com/a/970881/621125
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1348698/621125

But none of them work...
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

As expected, its an ubuntu issue and this answer help me to fix it :)

https://askubuntu.com/a/1273633/621125

edit :

From a quick look, the issue is a bad configuration of the current `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Replace this file by `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` file resolve my issue, here the commands I used :

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot may be necessary

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1247938)

Comment: you're right, I completed my answer