# Chromium command line "proxy-server" argument

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium, proxy

Quick question, if I want to set Chromium's HTTP Proxy via the command line argument `--proxy-server="USERhere:PASShere@127.0.0.1:8080` [as detailed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513840/google-chrome-proxy-settings), how would I go about entering a username that is an email address (so already includes an @ symbol)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do this. The (wild) claim is they don't support this for security reasons. Did you workaround a solution here?

Comment: My only solution was to ask my proxy provider to issue me with a username that was not my email address.

Comment: I could never get user:pass working (even without an email address in the username), even though this worked in other systems Chrome didn;t like it. I thought there was an issue about this somewhere...

Comment: @hayd same for me. How did you solve it? Use other browser?

Comment: @YueDeng For production I used squid instance in the end. I use a more intrusive VPN on my personal machine (that catches _every_ request not just from Chrome/Chromium).

Comment: @hayd Thanks! I also found a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888323/how-to-override-basic-authentication-in-selenium2-with-java-using-chrome-driver