# cannot access the internet via terminal after proxy configuration

Tags: proxy

I recently installed BackBox Linux. At first when I tried to connect to the from terminal using my USB broadband connection(no proxy) there was no any issue. Then I tried to set up proxy settings for our university's network.I followed the steps of the IZX's answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio) article. Then again I removed the text I changed, and tried to install some packages and tried to update, then terminal shows some errors like this

```
Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emacs23/emacs23_23.3+1-1ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to 3128:80 (0.0.12.56). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emacs23/emacs_23.3+1-1ubuntu9.2_all.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to 3128:80 (0.0.12.56). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**What should I do??**

Comment: Do `unset http_proxy https_proxy` and try again..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it did not work. I switched to ubuntu 14.04 and wifi works perfectly fine. Thanks again for the effort.