# Firefox redirecting from locahost to 192.168.x.x

Tags: 14.04, vpn, proxy, cisco

I am connecting to my corporate vpn using openconnect and network-manager-openconnect.  When I connected to the vpn, I tried navigating to localhost to hit my local web server where I was doing some development.

The page could not load and I could see `Connecting 192.168.233.38` (or some similar address) in the Firefox window.  If I use `http://127.0.0.1` this works fine.

Using `ping localhost` from a console works fine and shows `localhost` as `127.0.0.1`.

Very frustrating!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess openconnect configures http proxy to be used by FF. ('Connection through HTTP proxy, including libproxy support for automatic proxy configuration.') FF Preferences - Advanced - Network etc, you should exclude localhost.

Another option is a change of resolv.conf that will redirect even localhost. cat it.

I'd try wget -vvv and see exact step which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When I initially started firefox, it was set to use the system proxy.  According to this [unix stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102244/firefox-use-system-proxy-settings-but-where-are-these):

> The system proxy settings should be stored as system-wide variables, present in /etc/environment

In my case I set them in .pam_environment instead of /etc/environment.  However, I set only http_proxy and https_proxy but not no_proxy so the proxy was being used everywhere.

I was able to resolve the problem by:

1. Modifying .pam_environment with the [proxy server related environment variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio), setting no_proxy for localhost, etc. and logging out and then back in.
2. [Resetting Firefox according to the help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).