# why can't system proxy work while firefox/chrome works well with proxy?

Tags: proxy

I'm in a lab and have to use proxy for Internet access. 
I can set proxy on firefor/chrome (8080) and use the proxy to access Internet. But when I set the proxy on system setting of ubuntu(http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html), it doesn't work. WHy?

I tried `export http_proxy=[the proxy ip]:8080` on terminal, trying to connect Internet via my terminal, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for system wide proxy.
Edit the following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Set/Add: `http_proxy="http://yourproxyserver:8080"` (if you have password "http://user_name:password@yourproxyserver.com:8080/")
Same for https_proxy, ftp_proxy etc.

If you want exceptions (e.g. you want to use your localhost server): `no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"`

You need to restart to apply changes.

If you want to apply it for apt-get and some other tools, check this tutorial:
[How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio)

Comment: I tried `export http_proxy=[the proxy ip]:8080` on terminal, but it doesn't work on terminal,  how do you think of this? thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, it would work on CentOS, but not in Ubuntu. Try to edit the file as I explained.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't work