# Systemwide proxy settings in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, proxy

I wanted to use internet on my college proxy server which also requires authentication. I searched google for solutions and the best solution I found yet was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio?lq=1) . I have *modified the script* in the accepted answer to include authentication. Here it goes:

```
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
echo "This script must be run as root";
exit 1;
fi

if [ $# -eq 4 ] then

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual' ;
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host '$1';
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port $2;
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user '$3';
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password '$4';


grep PATH /etc/environment > lol.t;
printf \
"http_proxy=http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\n\
 https_proxy=http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\n\
 ftp_proxy=http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\n\
 no_proxy=\"localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com\"\n\
 HTTP_PROXY=http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\n\
 HTTPS_PROXY=http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\n\
 FTP_PROXY=http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\n\
 NO_PROXY=\"localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com\"\n" >> lol.t;

 cat lol.t > /etc/environment;


 printf \
 "Acquire::http::proxy \"http://$3:$4@$1:$2/\";\n\
  Acquire::ftp::proxy \"ftp://$3:$4@$1:$2/\";\n\
  Acquire::https::proxy \"https://$3:$4@$1:$2/\";\n" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies;

rm -rf lol.t;

else

printf "Usage $0 <proxy_ip> <proxy_port> <username> <password>\n";

fi
```

**However *Online accounts* still don't work(same for rhythmbox and other GTK3 programs)**. A white screen appears like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how it can be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Solved it finally:

(Follow the steps serially)

#### **1. For gtk3 programs such as rhythmbox and online accounts:**

First you need to enter proxy settings in network settings (along with authentication):

[image]

Then apply system wide.

#### **2. For apt,software center etc**

edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

And then replace all the existing text by the following lines

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@host:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@host:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@host:port/";
```

#### **3. Environment variables**

edit the file `/etc/environment`

And then add the following lines after PATH="something here"

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@host:port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

That's all..

Comment: Does step 1) alter /etc/environment? I'd like a way to do that step via the command line.

Comment: Seems step 1) works for `apt-get update` as well. So don't need step 2).

Comment: @Raman I there any need to escape the special characters in password while doing this?
If so then how?

Answer (score 3):

That’s not all, of course. Some more programs (`npm`, `curl` and `git`):

```
npm config set proxy $HTTP_PROXY
npm config set https-proxy $HTTPS_PROXY
npm config set strict-ssl false
echo "proxy = $HTTP_PROXY" > ~/.curlrc
echo "noproxy = $NO_PROXY" >> ~/.curlrc
git config --global http.proxy $HTTP_PROXY
git config --global https.proxy $HTTPS_PROXY
```

For Maven, edit `~/.m2/settings.xml`. IntelliJ does not seem to pick up the global config either.

Answer (score 2):

To make `wget` work with a proxy, I would add also to create a `.wgetrc` in your home directory, containing :

```
http_proxy = http://proxy:port/
https_proxy = http://proxy:port/
proxy_user = user
proxy_password = password
use_proxy = on
wait = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

To download packages by wget proxy have to be setup in /etc/environment, and to download packages by apt-get proxy have to be setup in /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, it is currently not providing much helpful information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)