# command to set socks proxy

Tags: command-line, scripts, proxy, system-settings, socks5

I'm using socks proxy over ssh tunnel

```
ssh -D 1080 -f -C -q -N <user>@<server>
```

when I set the proxy in `System settings > Network > Network proxy`, all applications like `Chromium, Firefox, apt, ...` are following the proxy.

[image]

now I want to write a shell script for automation,
how can I set `Network proxy` by terminal?

all I found is **"use some third-party software like `Tsocks` and ..."**.
but as I said, the ubuntu it self can do this without any third-party software so don't want to use them.

all I want is **set `Network proxy` using a command in terminal**.

Comment: Potentially a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/664777/systemwide-proxy-settings-in-ubuntu - check the accepted answer's 3rd point about `/etc/environment`, but using localhost instead eg `http_proxy=http://localhost:1080`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @taifwa said, [Systemwide proxy settings in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664777) was the solution.

and here is my script:

```
    ssh -D ${LOCAL_PORT} -f -C -q -N ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST} -p ${REMOTE_PORT}

    #set socks setting in System settings > Network > network proxy 
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port ${LOCAL_PORT}
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host 'localhost'
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '${LOCAL_RANGE}', '::1']"

    sudo su <<-EOF  
    #environment settings
    echo "socks_proxy='socks://localhost:${LOCAL_PORT}/'" >> /etc/environment 
    #apt settings
    echo "Acquire::socks::proxy 'socks://localhost:$LOCAL_PORT/';" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
    EOF
```

run as root is required for editing  `environment` and `apt.conf`,

edit:

---

but it's important to know editing `org.gnome.system.proxy` as root has no effect on current user, so them should run as normal user. so **don't run the script with sudo**

Comment: I know that this space isn't for saying thanks but you saved my whole day. I wish that I found this sooner.

Comment: Does this script only work for Gnome, not for Xfce?

Comment: I don't this test on Xface.

Comment: Using gsettings to set socks results in generating environmental variables 'ALL_PROXY' and 'all_proxy' as 'socks://xxx:yyy', which neglects the VERSION of socks. Do you know how to make gsettings generate these environmental variables as 'socks5://xxx:yyy' instead? This is important to me because many apps can't detect the version of socks automatically, including pip.