# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS How to force all http/https traffic to use proxy?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, proxy, network-bridge

I'm just switched back to Ubuntu, from Windows.
I had a program in Windows (Fiddler) which captured all outgoing traffic and could edit their header to use proxy.

Are there any way to force all of my outgoing traffic to use proxy?

If I have edited

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf
```

it does not work.

Someone proposed to use the system proxy settings.
**That panel edits this file**, but not even capable to use the proxy authentication.

Most of my program uses the proxy, but not all.

I tried also to run it from terminal and before running it I set up this:

```
tpeti@TLabs-MSI:~$ export http_porxy="http://username:password@ip:port"
tpeti@TLabs-MSI:~$ export https_porxy="https://username:password@ip:port"
```

But this didn't worked also.

Are there any way to force all programs to use proxy, or edit all the outgoing traffic headers to go through the proxy?

And can I do it, with just specific programs too?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `http_porxy` ≠ `http_proxy`

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify this proxies and apply them system wide. Just collect the IP and Ports for your HTTP and HTTPS proxies and do this with the system proxy setting GUI. Search for Network Proxy in dash.

Try **user_name:password@Proxy_IP** for the authentication. This seems to be the way to configure it in the configuration file. [source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html)

**Ubuntu Main**

[image: Search the dash]
[image: Initial view]
[image: Proxy settings]
[image: Input proxies here]
[image: user:password@ip]

**Mate** IN mate there's a checkbox for this if you click on *details*
[image: System-> Preferences-> Internet and Network-> Network Proxy]
[image]

Comment: Sorry but that not works. 
First, the Ubuntu 16.04 config panel don't look like that.
The second I told u that to set up the /etc/apt/apt.conf file doesent work. The config panel what you proposed edit the same file,  but not even can use the authentication. So thanks 4 the help, but what u propose dosen't work.

Comment: It's the same options as I used in 15.10, maybe there where changes in 16.04 I'll check out the auth detail.

Comment: Mmm yes sorry, that's how FF settings look

Comment: Thanks! It works with almoast all of my programs. Just not, with the crucial one. :/

Comment: Your solution with the unity networking isn't working (It saves the whole line as if it would be the IP of the proxy). But with mate the system switches on the defeault authentication. BUT DONT FORCE IT ON ALL THE PROGRAMS :( So it doesen't solve my problem, because more of my programs doesn't use authentication. We checked it on the proxy logs, they not even tried to use the proxy )

Comment: I don't use Gnome/dash (I use Xubuntu). What application/command starts this network settings? System -> network *via gmrun) runs network-admin  but that does not show proxy settings (only general, dns, hosts)

Comment: @djb http://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio

Comment: This works on ubuntu 16.04 an properly answers "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS How to force all http/https traffic to use proxy?"

I cannot see how the "/etc/apt/apt.conf" file is related to this question.