# Create a VPN Connection which connects to a Socks server

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn

I have a socks proxy server set up using Shadowsocks and I have the client on my laptop.

The problem is that I have to configure every single program (using HTTP_PROXY env or manually) to proxy through my socks server.

I wanted to create a VPN Connection in which I config my socks credentials so that when this VPN is connected ALL my network is going through the proxy and when I don't need it I just disconnect the VPN.

Are there any tools to define a new protocol or something in VPN section?

I tried OpenVPN but seems it's not supporting what I want:

My Computer -> VPN -> Socks -> Internet.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that I have to configure every single program (using
>   HTTP_PROXY env or manually) to proxy through my socks server.

Forward port `80` to your proxy's port (`8080` in here). A command like this would do this temporary (a restart would remove it).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85933/197095

To make this rule permanent, see this question and answer: [How can I make a specific set of iptables rules permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66890/how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent)

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to use `Socks` as tunneling protocol, so you can't make VPN using `Socks`. The reason is simple: `Socks` forwards only TCP (and UDP in `Socks5`), so other protocol can't pass through `Socks`.

You can use [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net) to pass every connection through your `Socks` proxy. It does same as Proxifire in MS-Windows.

Comment: ProxyChains works, but what if I want to create a VPN to my Socks connection so I can Hotspot my VPN connection? (Share a VPN connection). Or is there a way to pass the Socks through Hotspot?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But only TCP and DNS traffic is passed, which is enough in 99% cases.

On Openvpn server side, run a Socks5 client that supports opening a local REDIRECT socket and forwarding traffic to the next Socks5 server. My choice is Gost.

```
gost -L redirect://:12345 -F  socks5://U:P@Host:Port
```

Then main magic comes. Run actual DNS resolver that sends DNS via a proxy to the DNS server like Google via DoH.

```
https_dns_proxy -p 54000 -a 172.22.21.1 -b 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 \
  -vvvvvv -4 -t socks5://U:P@Host:Port
```

Using Gost, create a local DNS caching resolver, which will forward all DNS to the resolver above:

```
gost -L "dns://172.22.22.1:53000?mode=udp&dns=172.22.22.1:54000&ttl=300"
```

And redirect TCP and UDP (only DNS) of a VPN client to these things.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 172.22.21.100 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to 12345
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 172.22.21.100 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to 53000
```

You don't need net.ipv4.ip_forward to be 1 ! No NAT, no forwarding is done.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN solution is too complicated, but it is possible. You have to setup a VPN server and on the VPN server you need to setup a system wide proxy.

The only question is why not to setup the system wide proxy on your client instead of vpn as described here: http://askubuntu/questions/769361/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-force-all-http-https-traffic-to-use-proxy

In firefox there was a toggle proxy extension to swap the connection, nowadays there is a MM3 proxy switch for firefox quantum.

Comment: Fixed url: https://askubuntu.com/questions/769361/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-force-all-http-https-traffic-to-use-proxy