# How to use Socks5 across the whole system like a VPN?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, vpn, proxy, socks5

I'm looking for a way to use configured a Socks5 across the whole system including terminals, apps, browsers, etc.

For instance, I run a socks5 proxy on my localhost on port `1080` using V2ray or Shadowsocks or an SSH tunnel then I can use these proxies on my browsers via Firefox proxy configuration to listen from `1080` port or via FoxyProxy extension on the Chrome by the same way. Now, I'm going to find a way to use this across my whole system same as connecting to a VPN.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

*Please consider the current restrictions in Iran and don't close this post to be hopeful to get a to-the-point answer which is really grateful to us.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a VPN Connection which connects to a Socks server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980819/create-a-vpn-connection-which-connects-to-a-socks-server)

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/769361/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-force-all-http-https-traffic-to-use-proxy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set system-wide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-system-wide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio)

Comment: @user68186 thank you for your response, but this answer doesn't work for socks5 as other users also mentioned that

Comment: So far this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769378/772449) worked for me