# How to change Host (IP address) and port number to connect to wifi internet in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, hosts

I explain my situation: I downloaded from google play store NetShare app to make my smartphone as WiFi extender, it works with no problems, BUT I need to change the host name (IP address) and port number in my laptop to get it working!! My system is xubuntu 16.04 and there are NO options to do that via GUI!!! Any suggestions how to do that automatically???? I couldn't find so far a solution. thanks. vladi

Comment: Do you share the WLAN internet from your phone to your Ubuntu Laptop? I think you would be better off with USB Tethering, when the phone is connected to WiFi.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar yes the netshare app connects to xubuntu laptop via WLAN. I think using USB tethering is not a good solution! Because with WLAN I can place my smartphone anywhere to get better wifi speed!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Netshare Google Play store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.everyoneisaware.netshare&hl=en),

> This app will require you to manually setup a proxy for the client device with the IP address and the port shown.

So all you need to do is set up a proxy in Ubuntu, specifying your phone as the proxy server, along with the port for the proxy server. This is an already asked question, and for the answer, [refer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/151047/732822).

Comment: OHH!! yes these are all I need!!! thanks!!! vladi

Answer (score 1):

The firefox browser will allow you to easily set the Proxy if browser access is all you need. Click on the menu button ( top right of browser) and select preferences. Scroll down to network settings.
Click on settings.  Click on the manual proxy configuration button. Enter the 192.168.48.1 in HTTP proxy box,
enter 8282 in the Port box. Check the Also Use this proxy button
Click OK and you are done.